Side content at the same Y position, but stackable
I would like to create a sidebar with comments to the main text like in Google Docs.

I would like the comments to be at the same Y position as text, BUT if text is too long, or there are multiple comments they should not overlap but stack one under the other.
The best I could come up with is this:


<html>
<head>
<style>
p { max-width: 400px; position: relative; }
span { background: yellow; }
span::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 420px;
  width: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sagittis metus sit amet purus dapibus iaculis. Aenean facilisis malesuada orci, tincidunt bibendum erat. <span id="c1" data-text="Etiam commodo, purus eget gravida faucibus, ipsum mi maximus magna, eu tincidunt arcu arcu nec elit">Proin vel nisl lacinia, facilisis velit cursus, eleifend turpis. Phasellus ac imperdiet erat.</span> Donec egestas aliquam augue a mattis. <span id="c2" data-text="Cras ut nunc ac nunc pharetra gravida. Morbi pulvinar blandit justo id interdum. Sed risus orci, posuere id semper tempor, dignissim non turpis.">Pellentesque congue nunc vel scelerisque eleifend.</span> Fusce orci odio, ultricies posuere mi ac, elementum blandit dolor. Praesent non velit bibendum est feugiat egestas et nec urna. Etiam volutpat eu massa sed porttitor. Aliquam et pulvinar metus. Maecenas nec enim felis.</p>

<p>Ut mattis eros vitae risus scelerisque ornare ac tincidunt nibh. Suspendisse vitae ipsum porttitor, interdum nisl ut, sagittis arcu. In pretium, nulla vitae tincidunt vestibulum, odio neque convallis lacus, sit amet auctor leo tortor non nunc. Curabitur in dui at lorem mollis malesuada eget eget velit. <span id="c3" data-text="Ut ut viverra nisi. Integer imperdiet at nibh at bibendum. Etiam commodo, purus eget gravida faucibus, ipsum mi maximus magna.">Etiam vel neque vitae enim semper consequat</span> lacinia id urna. Nulla commodo tellus et nunc commodo, et vulputate nunc auctor. Curabitur nec gravida risus. Aliquam neque nulla, faucibus non ante sed, pharetra euismod purus. Pellentesque molestie ante in sapien varius facilisis. Fusce nec cursus diam.</p>

<p>Ut ut viverra nisi. Integer imperdiet at nibh at bibendum. Etiam commodo, purus eget gravida faucibus, ipsum mi maximus magna, eu tincidunt arcu arcu nec elit. Quisque ligula nibh, imperdiet hendrerit laoreet et, rhoncus vitae libero. Ut ornare leo sed nisl eleifend pretium non nec arcu. Aenean quis sollicitudin arcu, ac fermentum sem. Proin vitae velit a est ornare vestibulum. Vivamus finibus dui aliquam, ultricies quam eget, egestas eros. Cras ut nunc ac nunc pharetra gravida. Morbi pulvinar blandit justo id interdum. Sed risus orci, posuere id semper tempor, dignissim non turpis.</p>
</body>
</html>



which overlaps, and also this way it's impossible to add extra elements to the sidebar content like user name or avatar so I'm looking for a better solution

I don't think that's possible in just CSS, it might be worth mentioning if you are open to answers using JavaScript.

Yes, if it doesn't require me to use a specific framework then JS is acceptable

you should overthink your HTML structure and use aside for a comment sidebar instead of trying to place every single element absolutely.
